# How can I remove the sudden death time?

Tags: call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

I host a game where we friends play COD4, Sabotage on local.

When the time is over and no team was able to plant and defend the bomb, the sudden death starts for 90s. The exhausting thing here is that the lazy players in the game, they always try to waste those 90s like by NEVER coming out of a buliding to keep running away and cause the round to draw. Which is not fun at all.

Could someone please tell me a command with which I may completely remove those 90s or maybe change to some bigger number so that there won't ever be a draw?

Comment: AFAIK there is no command for this and I also don't remember any config setting to change sudden death behavior. Maybe there is a mod for this..